# Spring Security - JDBC authentication does not work, when correct credentials are passed

Tags: java, jdbc, spring-security

I have a problem with jdbc authentication in my application using Spring Security. Sometimes I'm able to login without any complications (passing correct credentials) but sometimes application shows "Bad credentials" on the login page (I'm sure that credentials are correct).

I'm using Spring Boot, Spring Security, MySQL, BCryptEncoder for storing passwords, tried to make a lot of modifications but result is still the same...

JDBC authentication code:

```java
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private DataSource dataSource;

    @Autowired
    protected void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {

        auth.jdbcAuthentication()
          .dataSource(dataSource)
          .usersByUsernameQuery("SELECT username, password, 'true' as enabled"
              + " FROM user WHERE username=?")
          .authoritiesByUsernameQuery("SELECT username, authority"
              + " FROM authorities WHERE username=?")
          .passwordEncoder(new BCryptPasswordEncoder());
    }
```

Spring security configuration:

```java
@Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/login")
                .permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/registration")
                .permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/forgot-password", "/reset**")
                .permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/**")
                .access("hasRole('ROLE_USER')")
            .and()
                .formLogin()
                .loginPage("/login")
                .defaultSuccessUrl("/")
                .usernameParameter("username")
                .passwordParameter("password")
            .and()
                .rememberMe()
                .rememberMeCookieName("home-budget-login-cookie")
                .tokenValiditySeconds(365 * 24 * 60 * 60)
                .rememberMeParameter("remember-me")
                .tokenRepository(persistentTokenRepository())
            .and()
                .logout()
                .permitAll()
                .deleteCookies("auth_code", "home-budget-login-cookie");

    }
```

Saving new user method (registration process):

```java
@Service("userService")
public class UserService {

    public void saveUser(User user, boolean updateMode) {
        user.setPassword(new BCryptPasswordEncoder().encode(user.getPassword()));
        user.setPasswordConfirm(new BCryptPasswordEncoder().encode(user.getPasswordConfirm()));
        user.setEnable(1);
        User userReturned = userRepository.save(user);

        if (!updateMode) {
            Authorities role = new Authorities();
            role.setUsername(userReturned.getUsername());
            role.setAuthority("ROLE_USER");

            roleRepository.save(role);
        }

    }

}
```

User Entity:

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "user")
public class User {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "user_id")
    private int id;

    @Column(name = "username")
    @NotNull
    private String username;

    @Column(name = "email")
    @Email(message = "Please provide a valid e-mail")
    @NotNull
    private String email;

    @Column(name = "password")
    @NotNull
    private String password;

    @Column(name = "password_confirm")
    @NotNull
    private String passwordConfirm;

    @Column(name = "enabled")
    private int enable;

    @Column(name = "reset_token")
    private String resetToken;
```

I expect application will log me in without any problems, during passing correct credentials. Is there any better method than jdbc authentication?

Comment: Why don't you try JPA authentication ? It's easier than JDBC

Comment: I was looking for good tutorial and found this JDBC authentication method which worked for most cases, but recently I have a critical problem with logging in my application. Do you have any good tutorials about JPA authentication?

Comment: I don't know, but maybe you can authenticate with an user from memory, like in this tutorial https://spring.io/guides/gs/securing-web/

Comment: @outlaw1988 Show your password from login page and your encoded password from your database.

Comment: @Alexandra I've found good tutorial here https://hellokoding.com/registration-and-login-example-with-spring-security-spring-boot-spring-data-jpa-hsql-jsp/ Now it works!

Comment: Nice!  Keep going!